# Elm : How to apply List.map on Nested List

Tags: nested-lists, elm

This is the basic work i have done with simple List Float

```
renderCoordinates : List Float -> Html Msg
renderCoordinates coordinates =
    ol [ type_ "A"]
        (List.map (\coordinate -> li [] [text (String.fromFloat coordinate)]) coordinates)
```

When it comes to `List (List(List Float))` and  i am stuck. I am wonder if i can do it this way?

```
renderCoordinates : List (List(List Float)) -> Html Msg
renderCoordinates coordinates =
    ol [ type_ "A"]
        (List.map (List.map (\coordinate -> li [] [text (String.fromFloat coordinate)]) ) coordinates)
```

-- `List.map (List.map (List.map (\coordinate -> li [] [text (String.fromFloat coordinate)]) ) ) coordinates doesnt work as well`

Basically i wish to display each items in the list of `List (List(List Float))`...
Any help is appreciate !

**Updates**

With the help of @Simon 
I made some modification of code to make it works like :

```
renderCoordinates : List (List (List Float)) -> Html Msg
renderCoordinates coordinates =
    let
        map1 : List (List (List Float)) -> List (Html Msg) 
        map1 lists =
            List.concatMap map2 lists

        map2 : List (List Float) -> List (Html Msg)
        map2 floats =
            List.map (\coordinate -> li [] [ text (Debug.toString coordinate) ]) floats
    in
    ol [ type_ "A" ]
        (map1 coordinates)
```

This will print `A: [X, Y]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it in parts and concat the results at each stage

```
renderCoordinates : List (List (List Float)) -> Html Msg
renderCoordinates coordinates =
    let
        map1 : List (List Float) -> List (Html Msg)
        map1 lists =
            L.concatMap map2 lists

        map2 : List Float -> List (Html Msg)
        map2 floats =
            List.map (\coordinate -> li [] [ text (String.fromFloat coordinate) ]) floats
    in
    ol [ type_ "A" ]
        (List.concatMap map1 coordinates)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @SimonH ! I made some modification of code and it works !  i will update it in my question !

Comment: And there is a mistake in line `map1 : List (List Float) -> Html Msg` ... It should be `map1 : List (List Float) -> List (Html Msg)` ? The output prints every items in the list like 
`A: coord[0].X , B: coord[0].Y C: coord[1].X , D: coord[1].Y`